# Proper Gas Pipe size

Tags: natural-gas

I have a contractor who gave me a quote to replace a 72' outdoor gas line to a 400K BTU pool/spa. The previous line was 3/4" IPS and that is also the current line size that is coming from the Meter. His quote states 1" PE IPS gas pipe. The meter is an AC-630 and the pressure regulator is an 1813C, both from American Meter company. I'm assuming the pressure is 2 PSIG since 3/4" pipe was previously used and the spa heater worked fine, but I haven't had a pressure test done. I'm looking for feedback whether he is ok in going from 3/4 IPS to 1" PE IPS pipe or if he should have quoted 3/4" PE IPS pipe. I asked him about whether it was the proper size, but he didn't respond back. I would like your feedback before I qet a new quote. Thanks.

Comment: 1" will reduce the pressure drop over the length of the run. With that large of a heating unit I hope you have 2 PSI most residential in my area is limited to 3/4 psi with 2 psi being for commercial and large heaters like you have.

Comment: Does your pool heater have a pressure reducer to go from 2 psig to 7" WC (0.25 psig)? My guess is that the plumber was thinking the line was at 7" WC. Why do you want to replace the existing 72' of 3/4" gas line?

Comment: Yes, it has a pressure reducer at the pool heater.  The old 3/4 iron pipe is rusted out. I live in Florida.

Comment: Any labeling on the pressure reducer at the pool heater? Link below states that the 1813C regulator has an outlet pressure range of 3.5"WC to 2 psig and inlet up to 125 psig.  http://mcsmeters.com/products/gas-pressure-regulator-1813c

Comment: It is a Maxitrol 325 7AL, 2 PSIG Class I Po 7"-11"